# Increasing NetBeans WAR file size

Tags: limit, war, netbeans-8

I am currently figuring out how to increase the limits to creating of JAR/WAR file on this platform. My project is rather large, around 17GB. May I know how can I bypass the 4GB threshold when creating the WAR file?

[image: After Clean & Build Project on NetBeans]

Comment: Not that it matters much, but I have to ask: what in the world are you doing to require a 17GB WAR?

Comment: Oops sorry. The project is 17GB but it is around 6GB when creating the WAR file.

Comment: Still a lot, if you ask me. Is the bulk made of stuff you could somehow externalize?

Comment: I am developing an episodic memory application so there's quite a number of folders with images. Thanks for the advice. I will externalize the information.